# How to know the URL of my local git repo?

Tags: git

I've just created a new git repo on my remote server using `git init` command.

And now, i want to add that repo on my local pc using `git remote add <alias> <remote_repo_url>` command.

My problem is, i don't know what is my `remote_repo_url`. Someone mentions about referring in .git/config file but nothing in it seems like a URL:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
```

Comment: How do you plan to access the repo?  Via https?  ssh?  Network filesystem?

Comment: I am using SSH ...

Answer (score -1):

You add it from github project repo it's something like that `https://github.com/yourgithubName/yourRepo` this remote Url, or you can use `ssh URL` by creating `ssh key` to do [so](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to host the repository somewhere. Most people use Github, or BitBucket, or GitLabs. So you'll have to create a repository there (either manually or through the CLI), and then add a remote URL to your current git repository.

But to answer your specific question, to know the URL of your remotes:

`git remote -v`

That's the answer, but not the answer to what you're really looking for.